# Libgdx tween not working on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, tween

I'm developing my first android game with libgdx, using as a base this amazing tutorial (http://www.kilobolt.com/day-11-supporting-iosandroid--splashscreen-menus-and-tweening.html). Everything works properly except for the tweening that I’m using in the splash screen to show the logo of my “company”. The weird part is that the logo works just fine in the desktop version, but in the android version is not being showed.

I’m using the same class that they used in the app developed in the tutorial. By the way, this app’s splash screen works fine in both versions.

I have compared my app and the tutorial’s app, but I found no differences except for this on the package explorer. I don't know if it means something:

http://i1223.photobucket.com/albums/dd507/victormmenendez/tut.jpg

```
package com.victor.Screens;

import aurelienribon.tweenengine.BaseTween;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.Tween;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenCallback;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenEquations;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.victor.TweenAccessors.SpriteAccessor;
import com.victor.FZHelpers.AssetLoader;
import com.victor.FZombies.FZGame;

public class SplashScreen implements Screen
{

    private TweenManager manager;
    private SpriteBatch batcher;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private FZGame game;

    public SplashScreen(FZGame game)
    {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        sprite = new Sprite(AssetLoader.logo);
        sprite.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0);

        float width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        float desiredWidth = width * .4f;
        float scale = desiredWidth / sprite.getWidth();

        sprite.setSize(sprite.getWidth() * scale, sprite.getHeight() * scale);
        sprite.setPosition((width / 2) - (sprite.getWidth() / 2), (height / 2) - (sprite.getHeight() / 2));
        setupTween();
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();

    }

    private void setupTween()
    {
        Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());
        manager = new TweenManager();

        TweenCallback cb = new TweenCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int type, BaseTween<?> source)
            {
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen());
            }
        };

        Tween.to(sprite, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, .8f).target(1).ease(TweenEquations.easeInOutQuad).repeatYoyo(1, .4f).setCallback(cb).setCallbackTriggers(TweenCallback.COMPLETE).start(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta)
    {
        manager.update(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batcher.begin();
        sprite.draw(batcher);
        batcher.end();
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help. I'm sorry if in any moment I couldn’t explain myself, but English is not my primary language. If you need any extra piece of code, I can add it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you export the tween jar files in your Build Path. For Eclipse, you can Right-click on the project, choose "Build Path" > "Configure Build Path", go to the "Order and Export" tab on the right side, and make sure that the tween jar files are checked in the list there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked that and actually one of the jar files wasn't checked, but it didn't fixed it

Comment: Actually it looks like my own project doesn't have those being exported so I guess that is not the problem. If it works in the desktop but not the Android I would suggest making sure the texture width and height is a power of 2 (like 16, 32, 64... etc). Sometimes depending on the version of OpenGL your android device is using it will require textures be powers of 2. This has caused stuff not to be rendered for me in my Nexus 7 or to be rendered with a white block. Check that first.