# App crashes in emulator using libgdx and tween engine

Tags: java, android, libgdx, emulation, tween

I'm currently working on a project and so far only have the splash and main screen done. I wanted to see how it would run in an Android environment so I ran it as an Android Application. The emulator booted up just fine but when it load the app or *"Uploading Project-android.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
Installing Project-android.apk..."* it prompts up that it "Unfortunately, Project has stopped. Here I copied the logcat for reference.

```
06-26 23:33:53.190: D/dalvikvm(1808): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already     on)
06-26 23:33:53.280: D/dalvikvm(1808): Trying to load lib /data/app-    lib/com.levellabs.project.android-2/libgdx.so 0xb1fbed48
06-26 23:33:53.280: D/dalvikvm(1808): Added shared lib /data/app-    lib/com.levellabs.project.android-2/libgdx.so 0xb1fbed48
06-26 23:33:53.280: D/dalvikvm(1808): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-    lib/com.levellabs.project.android-2/libgdx.so 0xb1fbed48, skipping init
06-26 23:33:53.280: D/(1808): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection     established 0xb90f3dc0, tid 1808
06-26 23:33:53.460: I/AndroidInput(1808): sensor listener setup
06-26 23:33:53.550: W/EGL_emulation(1808): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-26 23:33:53.550: D/OpenGLRenderer(1808): Enabling debug mode 0
06-26 23:33:53.560: D/(1808): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection     established 0xb910b590, tid 1823
06-26 23:33:53.600: W/GL2JNIView(1808): creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
06-26 23:33:53.800: D/dalvikvm(1808): Trying to load lib /data/app-    lib/com.levellabs.project.android-2/libgdx.so 0xb1fbed48
06-26 23:33:53.800: D/dalvikvm(1808): Shared lib '/data/app-    lib/com.levellabs.project.android-2/libgdx.so' already loaded in same CL     0xb1fbed48
06-26 23:33:53.800: I/GL2(1808): all initialized 2
06-26 23:33:53.800: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): OGL renderer: Android Emulator     OpenGL ES Translator (GeForce GTX 770/PCIe/SSE2)
06-26 23:33:53.800: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): OGL vendor: Google (NVIDIA     Corporation)
06-26 23:33:53.800: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): OGL version: OpenGL ES 2.0 (4.5.0     NVIDIA 350.12)
06-26 23:33:53.800: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): OGL extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker     GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32     GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear     GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture     GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear     GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot     GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
06-26 23:33:53.800: E/EGL_emulation(1808): [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
06-26 23:33:53.800: E/EGL_emulation(1808): tid 1823: eglGetConfigAttrib(605):     error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-26 23:33:53.800: E/EGL_emulation(1808): [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
06-26 23:33:53.800: E/EGL_emulation(1808): tid 1823: eglGetConfigAttrib(605):     error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-26 23:33:53.800: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): framebuffer: (5, 6, 5, 0)
06-26 23:33:53.800: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): depthbuffer: (24)
06-26 23:33:53.800: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): stencilbuffer: (0)
06-26 23:33:53.800: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): samples: (0)
06-26 23:33:53.800: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): coverage sampling: (false)
06-26 23:33:53.810: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): Managed meshes/app: { }
06-26 23:33:53.810: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): Managed textures/app: { }
06-26 23:33:53.810: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): Managed cubemap/app: { }
06-26 23:33:53.810: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): Managed shaders/app: { }
06-26 23:33:53.810: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): Managed buffers/app: { }
06-26 23:33:55.540: I/dalvikvm(1808): Could not find method     aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager.update, referenced from method     com.levellabs.project.GameScreen.render
06-26 23:33:55.540: W/dalvikvm(1808): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method     369: Laurelienribon/tweenengine/TweenManager;.update (F)V
06-26 23:33:55.540: D/dalvikvm(1808): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
06-26 23:33:55.540: D/dalvikvm(1808): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 407K, 14% free     2931K/3392K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-26 23:33:55.540: E/dalvikvm(1808): Could not find class     'aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager', referenced from method     com.levellabs.project.GameScreen.show
06-26 23:33:55.540: W/dalvikvm(1808): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance     100     (Laurelienribon/tweenengine/TweenManager;) in Lcom/levellabs/project/GameScreen;
06-26 23:33:55.540: D/dalvikvm(1808): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x001e
06-26 23:33:55.540: D/dalvikvm(1808): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0170     at 0x20 in Lcom/levellabs/project/GameScreen;.show
06-26 23:33:55.540: I/dalvikvm(1808): Failed resolving     Lcom/levellabs/project/tween/SpriteAccessor; interface 98     'Laurelienribon/tweenengine/TweenAccessor;'
06-26 23:33:55.540: W/dalvikvm(1808): Link of class     'Lcom/levellabs/project/tween/SpriteAccessor;' failed
06-26 23:33:55.540: D/dalvikvm(1808): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x345e     at 0x29 in Lcom/levellabs/project/GameScreen;.show
06-26 23:33:55.540: I/dalvikvm(1808): Failed resolving     Lcom/levellabs/project/GameScreen$1; interface 99     'Laurelienribon/tweenengine/TweenCallback;'
06-26 23:33:55.540: W/dalvikvm(1808): Link of class     'Lcom/levellabs/project/GameScreen$1;' failed
06-26 23:33:55.540: D/dalvikvm(1808): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x3434     at 0x54 in Lcom/levellabs/project/GameScreen;.show
06-26 23:33:55.660: D/dalvikvm(1808): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 9% free     3192K/3472K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-26 23:33:56.120: W/dalvikvm(1808): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0xb1cecb20)
06-26 23:33:56.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1808): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 75
06-26 23:33:56.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1808): Process: com.levellabs.project.android, PID: 1808
06-26 23:33:56.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1808): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager
06-26 23:33:56.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at com.levellabs.project.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:68)
06-26 23:33:56.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
06-26 23:33:56.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at com.levellabs.project.Project.create(Project.java:24)
06-26 23:33:56.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphi    cs.java:241)
06-26 23:33:56.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1808):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1512)
06-26 23:33:56.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1808): at  android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
06-26 23:33:56.130: I/AndroidInput(1808): sensor listener tear down
06-26 23:33:56.130: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): Managed meshes/app: { }
06-26 23:33:56.130: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): Managed textures/app: { }
06-26 23:33:56.130: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): Managed cubemap/app: { }
06-26 23:33:56.130: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): Managed shaders/app: { }
06-26 23:33:56.130: I/AndroidGraphics(1808): Managed buffers/app: { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your jar file version which has some native functions does not matches the **libgdx.so** file version which does not have that method. Better you compile the c++ libgdx library using **Android NDK** to match the native functions. I got this from your error

```
No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-    lib/com.levellabs.project.android-2/libgdx.so 0xb1fbed48, skipping init
......
......
Could not find method     aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager.update, referenced from method     com.levellabs.project.GameScreen.render
```

This means some of the native methods are not properly binded by the JNI

If you are running inside an emulator, you need corresponding **.so** files live **libgdx.....so** files

Refer this [Android ndk + libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219966/android-ndk-libgdx)

If you want the ready made JAR files and **.so** files download here http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/

You can see there are **11** JAR files and folders like armeabi/  armeabi-v7a/  x86/

Go through the README files for further setup needs and compilations steps.

There is also a **success** comment here [Libgdx tween not working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080642/libgdx-tween-not-working-on-android)

You can also download the Demo App https://java-universal-tween-engine.googlecode.com/files/tween-engine-demo-6.3.0.zip and check the **libs** folder inside it for the JAR files

If you need more help, ping me via https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/androidians chat room, I will help you